# How can I detect when the cursor changes to I-beam in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a custom cursor in my flash project. By default the custom cursor remains visible when you hover over a textfield and you get the I-beam cursor and your custom cursor visible at the same time. To avoid this I need to hide my custom cursor whenever the I-beam cursor appears (i.e. when you hover the mouse over a textfield). Also the cursor is always set to MouseCursor.AUTO state. So how can I detect when it changes to I-beam?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately I am pretty confident that there aren't any events that will track the state of the system cursor display. You may just have to add event listeners to the text fields themselves (roll over and roll out) and manage it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that tries to mimic what you want, it adds a single event listener to the stage and detects if roll over/out events happen on text fields and changes the cursor accordinly :

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    import flash.ui.MouseCursor;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        private var textField1:TextField = new TextField();
        private var textField2:TextField = new TextField();

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.load(new URLRequest('bg.png'));
            addChild(loader);               

            textField1.text = "Text Field 1";
            textField1.border = true;
            textField1.x = 100;
            addChild(textField1);

            textField2.text = "Text Field 2";
            textField2.border = true;
            textField1.x = 400;
            addChild(textField2);

            Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.HAND;

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onRollOver, true);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onRollOut, true);
        }

        private function onRollOver(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            var tf:TextField = e.target as TextField;
            if (tf)
            {
                Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.IBEAM;
                //hide your custom cursor here
            }
        }

        private function onRollOut(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            var tf:TextField = e.target as TextField;
            if (tf)
            {
                Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.HAND;
                //show your custom cursor here
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `ROLL_*` events only happen once, I think you're looking for the `MOUSE_*` events.

Comment: I think roll events are fine in this case, they will be trigged once the cursor goes over the TextField and the cursor will be changed, it will be trigged again when the cursor leaves and the cursor will be changed back. No need to set the cursor to IBEAM constantly by using MOUSE_* events.

Comment: Yes I did. It is working for me, the cursor changes to IBEAM over the text field and once it leaves the text field it changes to hand.

Comment: can you try again with a large bitmap background behind the two textfields and see if it still does it?